# Not working "CORS" with Vue js and Laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, cors

working with Laravel 5.7 and Mysql and Vue.js in my app. frontend is running using Vue.js and backend running with Laravel 5.7 and both front end and back end are connected using "CORS".(to save data to the MySQL table) https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors but when I run front end and try to save data following error msg is occurred in the console

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/addItem. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I have the following code in my Product.vue file:

```
methods:{
    submitForm(){
        this.$http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/addItem",this.item)
        .then(function (responce){
            this.$router.push('/list')
        })
    }
}
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? (You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.)

Comment: what did you mean 'the HTTP status code of the response?'

Comment: When you open your browser's network tab there should be an OPTIONS request sent out. Can you share the request and response headers of this request?

Comment: You have spelt response incorrectly, you have put responce